# I am a Bangladeshi in the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia holding a resident work permit. How can I visit Kuwait?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, saudi-arabia, bangladeshi-citizens, kuwait

I am a Bangladeshi national and hold a resident permit for the Kingdom of Saudia Arabia, where I am now.

How can I visit Kuwait. What are the visa requirements?

Comment: This has all your answers https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you want to go to Kuwait for tourism. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The State of Kuwait [Ministry of Interior e-Visa issuing service](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do) notes, that as a GCC resident, you may be able to [apply for an e-Visa](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/visaPubApp10.do?lng=eng), as long as you meet a number of additional conditions,

> GCC residents can apply for e-Visa if they have residency in one of the GCC countries (Saudi Arabia-Bahrain-Qatar-United Arab Emirates-Oman)
>
> - The validity of the GCC residency must exceed six months when applying for e-Visa.
> - A copy of the Sponsor's GCC residency should be sent along with each e-Visa application for all of the dependents i.e: ( spouse, children, domestic labor etc).
> - The main applicant (Sponsor) should be present with the dependents upon arrival to Kuwait.
> - The applicant's profession according to the GCC residency should be one of the following: Businessmen, Consultants, Diplomatic Corps, Doctors, Engineers, Lawyers, Judges & Members of Public Prosecution, Managers, University Teachers, Press & Media Staff, Pilots, System Analysts & Computer Programmers, University Graduates, Owners, Managers and Representatives of Commercial Companies and Establishments